# MediaWiki Not Displaying Any Recent Changes

Tags: mediawiki

New MediaWiki Installation Not showing any recent changes:-

[No Recent Changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xTYK.png)

Product Version

MediaWiki   1.31.1

PHP 7.2.10 (cgi-fcgi)

MySQL   8.0.12

Lua 5.1.4

No ideas where to begin troubleshooting this issue.

Comment: The obvious reason would be there not being any recent changes. Given you said it's a new installation, have you done any edits yet?

Comment: Hello, yes, it is a new installation, but only by a few weeks, the recentchanges table has lots of entries. We have created a number of pages and edits.

Answer (score 0):

Identified as users created changes where had the bot right and therefor changes where hidden by default.

Removed bot right and removed bot flag in DB and working now as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Recent changes and changes will be displayed for few days in special:recentchanges. Then it will by hidden, even if there is no new changes. Usually it remain in the recentchanges page for 3-7 days.

But if you make a new edits to your wiki, and not found it in the recentchanges page, then there is chance that your account has a bot flag. To solve that click the option "Show bots" in the recentchanges page. Or remove the bot flag from your account.